# chrome.downloads.erase not working When initiated from content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a Chrome extension that when entering a certain site. I am deleting the download history. I am using this from the background page:

```
chrome.downloads.erase({},
function(item)
{
    console.log("Erased item");
    console.log(item);
});
```

The problem is that it is not working when I am sending a message from the contact script after entering the url I wanted.

I use send Message in the content script

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage
```

and receive the message in the background page

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener
```

This is the output I get although there are some files in the download history:

```
Erased item
Array[0]
```

If I run the erase() from within the background page console it works fine

it seems that it happens because there is no user interaction.
If I put a clear button and click on it the deletion does works
But if I use timeout it does not 
Any Idea why it happens?

I have seen that it has something to do with the setTimeout
This works in the background page:

```
setTimeout(function(){
console.log('erasing downloads');
chrome.downloads.erase({});
}
, 0);
```

But this does not:

```
setTimeout(function(){
console.log('erasing downloads');
chrome.downloads.erase({});
}
, 1000);
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to nuke the entire download history?

Comment: Yes. Clear the entire download history

Comment: Considering your last edit: it's possible that it's intentional but not documented. Try running the code in the background console, but wrapped in a `setTimeout(func, 0)`.

Comment: It does have something to do with the set timeout. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: It this point I suggest to submit a bug at https://crbug.com/ and see if Chrome devs have any comments. This definitely seems like a lapse in documentation (everything more or less points to requiring user action).

Comment: I submitted a bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=419860

Answer (score 1):

I think I had finally found the reason for the problem.
After downloading I have closed Chrome with taskkill /f, like this:

taskKill /im "chrome.exe" /f

After reopening Chrome I got in this line in the download page:

thefilenamedownloaded.exe The browser crashed before the download completed.

If I used taskKill /im "chrome.exe" (without /f) than the problem did not happen.
The bug may be actually more complicated than this because that when I had user interaction its also worked. But for now it solved my problem. Hopes this help anyone else